# Redirect all the subfolders to root

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Recently I migrated the WordPress website **domainA.com** to the **domainB.com**. But my **old users** going to the **domainA.com**. So I created a basic HTML file to introduce the new website. Both websites have the same pages after migration. I mean If has **domainA.com/subpage1/post1**, the same in **domainB.com/subpage1/post1**. Now **domainA.com** has only 1 HTML file in the root Directory.

I solved this problem with Redirect all requests from **domainA.com** to **domainB.com**. Even If the user enters **domainA.com/subpage1/post**, it will redirect to **domainB.com/subpage1/post1**. It's worked perfectly with .htaccess. But this redirect process took a long time to redirect. That's why I created an HTML file and Link to **domainB.com**.

I hope you will understand. My question is:
How can I redirect all subfolders from **domainA.com** to **domainA.com**? If someone went to domainA.com/contact-us, they will get a 404 error. So I want to redirect **any parameters** after (**domainA.com/**) to **domainA.com**.

I add these rules in .htaccess but it will give this error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainA.com/$1
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://domainA.com [R=301,NC,L]
```

Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: _"But this redirect process took a long time to redirect."_ - did you implement it in .htaccess? Then there is no apparent reason, why it should take a long time. Or did you do this inside WordPress ...?

Comment: Yes, I used .htaccess to redirect. I think my hosting response time is slow. That's why it took a long time to redirect. So I decided to do this step.